# How do I check for a web address and reject an email with regex?

Tags: regex, email, webaddress

Where I'm running into a roadblock is trying to check for this

```
(?<http>(http|ftp|https):\/\/)?(?<address>([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?)
```

while rejecting the expression if it contains the @ sign.

I've tried a number of variations on this with no success.

What would work is if I can tell it to make sure that there are no `@` characters in it but I don't want to require a character using the `[^@]` syntax.  So how do I tell regex to accept `\w` and reject `@` at the same time.  I can't do `[\w^@]` to the best of my knowledge.

My Difficulty is that I'm using regex replace.  Ar you suggesting then that I use a placeholder and ten match against that afterwards?

Comment: Some examples of valid and invalid text would be helpful

Comment: www.cnn.com is a valid address jim@cnn.com is not and should not be altered.

Comment: Even if you don't want to allow username@ URLs, http://www.example.com/foo?x=y@z is still a valid address. Validating either an e-mail address or a URL is very vrey hard to do properly in regex; allowing a bare hostname to work as a URL too makes it even less possible.

Comment: I just need to make sure that when I do regex.replace that hte replacement doesn't include the @ symbol.  That's my only hangup here.  I've tried negative lookbehind and that doens't seem work either.

Comment: It has to be on one line all together.  The problem occurs when it starts to match the domain in the email and thinks that it's a web address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to get everything into one regex.  You could for example, match against your existing regex, then check with a secondary regex that the string doesn't have an @-sign.

Comment: Yep, does not need to be one regex for one task. Mulitple regexs are maybe clearer. Maybe this link can give some more hints: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ned. Use two regular expressions. You can get them from several sources, including http://regexlib.com/